# Shared file in memory between Lambda instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I have quite a large file (2.5 gigabits) that I'd like to be able to read from via a Lambda instance. It is a CDB file, thus the entirety of it needs to be available to the function.

Conceptually, the function container itself would need to load the entire file into memory before reading it. Is this the gist of it, or is there a way to do this in a shared fashion between all containers? Something like EFS.

Comment: What is a "CDB file"? CardScan DataBase?

Comment: Its a portable database format: https://cr.yp.to/cdb.html

Comment: 2.5 gigabits, or 2.5 gigabytes? The maximum RAM that can be allocated to an AWS Lambda function is around 3GB. The cost of running the Lambda function is based on memory size, so it will increase the cost of running the function. Memory cannot be shared between concurrent Lambda functions, but container reuse means that a function can be re-used so it only needs to load the data once (assuming it is read-only data). Amazon EFS can be used to provide shared storage that multiple instances of the function can access. Is this data that is going to be **updated**?

Comment: It's not going to be updated. Yeah the memory limit is something I'm concerned about.

Comment: If the data was loaded into a global variable, it would be available for subsequent executions. You only pay while the function is running, so "keeping the data in memory" is effectively free between executions, at least until the contain is destroyed. If the function is accessed often enough to keep it active, it could work out quite cost-effective.